# C memory board game error: Read access violation

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, c-strings

I am doing some improvements to a game I created with C language.
the project was a memory board game where there are 2 tables, a table for numbers and a table for letters, where the player has to select 2 numbers with matching letters.

the numbers table is a character array, where after each correct guess, the numbers in the table are replaced with the corresponding letters from the letters table.

the error happens in a part of the function where the program is supposed to print the numbers array.
(I have set the formal array parameter size to 8x8 to accommodate for all levels of the game).

The player chooses the numbers in the *ConditionCheck* function where the program makes sure the number is valid.

```
void NumInput(char numbers[8][8], int rows, int columns)
{
    int i, j, n1, n2;
    printf("Choose 2 numbers from the table below: \n\n");       /// print the numbers array
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            if (isalpha(numbers[i][j]) != 0)        //  if the array literal is a letter
                printf("%2c  ", numbers[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%2d  ", numbers[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    n1 = ConditionCheck(1, rows * columns);
    n2 = ConditionCheck(2, rows * columns);
    N1 = &n1;
    N2 = &n2;
    return;
}
```

that is where I get: **read access violation.
numbers was 0x11100DE** in the 8th line (if selection)

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: 
I have initialized the array in the main game function.

```
char numbers[9][9];
k = 1;
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)                /// initializing 'numbers' array
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            numbers[i][j] = k;
            k++;
        }
```

I called the function *NumInput* couple of lines later in the same main game function:

```
while (countdown >= 0 && !win)
    {
        time1 = clock();
        NumInput(numbers[rows][columns], rows, columns);
        num1 = *N1;
        num2 = *N2;
```

**NOTE:** *N1* and *N2* are integer pointers to access the numbers chosen by the player in the *NumInput* function

Comment: Always use braces - stops being caught with your trousers down

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is not productive to debug incomplete code. At a minimum we need to see how the function is called. So please provide a MVE that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it's quite likely that the two-dimensional array is tripping you up. From where you say the access violation is occurring, it looks like the array read, so what you've passed in to the function doesn't line up with how you're accessing it.

You haven't shown how you are allocating this array in the first place; this detail is crucial.

Comment: I have added more info for further clarification

Comment: What I found weird, is that, in main, you are declaring numbers as [9][9] and then in the NumInput[8][8]. Also, what are the values of rows and columns?

Comment: Also, take a look at, how properly pass arrays to function: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays-functions

Comment: I have solved the problem by passing only the array name (numbers) to the function. Thank you